# How to skip the rows using jquery :not

Tags: jquery

I stuck the issue for skipping row using jQuery `:not`. Here I adding rows dynamically and have some `<tr>` have one class `addBgColor`. Once we click on `submit` I would like to convert all table data to the `xml` strucuted data except the row contains `"addBgColor"` class, here is the code what I tried, please help me

```
var elements = $(".multipleData tr:not(.addBgColor) td input:checked");
    var size = elements.size();
    bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet + "<count>" + size + "</count>";
    elements.each(function() {    
            var tdValue = $(this).parent().next('td').html().trim();        
        bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet + "<row><eventid>";          
            bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet +  tdValue;
                bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet + "</eventid></row>";
    });
```

Comment: What is the problem? `tr:not(.addBgColor)` does what you want.

Comment: Have you tried enquoting the `.addBgColor` selector in the `:not()`?

Comment: Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/LfjSG/1321/ , issue is it didn't skipped the row contains class, getting all values.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney There is no need to use quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct your `html` nesting and everything will run just fine. There's no `tbody` start tag & all `tr`'s doesnt' have endings. Here's fixed [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LfjSG/1322/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#idXmlData").click(function(){
    var xmlStart =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\">";
    var xmlFirstRowSet = "<event>";
   var xmlLast="</event>";
    var headerRowSet='';
    xmlFirstRowSet = xmlFirstRowSet + headerRowSet;
    var bodyRowSet ='';
    
    var elements = $(".multipleData tr:not(.addBgColor) td input:checked");
    var size = elements.size();
    bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet + "<count>" + size + "</count>";
    elements.each(function() {    
      var tdValue = $(this).parent().next('td').html().trim();        
        bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet + "<row><eventid>";          
            bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet +  tdValue;
          bodyRowSet = bodyRowSet + "</eventid></row>";
    });
    
    var xml = xmlStart + xmlFirstRowSet + bodyRowSet+xmlLast;
     window.alert(xml);   
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="multipleData" style="border:1px solid #000000;">

<tbody>
 <tr> 
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" id="" name=""/>
  </td>
  <td>
   test1
  </td>
      </tr>
 <tr  class="addBgColor">
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" id="" name=""/>
  </td>
  <td>
   test2
  </td>
      </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" id="" name=""/>
  </td>
  <td>
   test3
  </td>
    </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" id="" name=""/>
  </td>
  <td>
   test4
  </td>
 </tr>

      
     </tbody>
</table>

  <input type="button" name="" value="XML Data" id="idXmlData" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As your jsfiddle code please update the HTML code for the table was not correct please update to as below:

```
 <table class="multipleData" style="border:1px solid #000000;">


<tr>    
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="" name=""/>
    </td>
    <td>
        test1
    </td>
  <td>
</tr>
<tr  class="addBgColor">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="" name=""/>
    </td>
    <td>
        test2
    </td>
  <td>
</tr>

<tr>    
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="" name=""/>
    </td>
    <td>
        test3
    </td>
  <td>
</tr>

<tr>    
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="" name=""/>
    </td>
    <td>
        test4
    </td>
</tr>

 </tbody>
```